# Reize browser window from bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, resize

Looking for a way to resize the browser window from a modal. Either by when the modal opens or if a button is clicked.

Tried window.resizeBy(); and window.resizeTo(); but not sure what to use/edit for "window". I did try "this" and "parent" but did not work...

Comment: Can you post your current attempts? `window.resizeBy` and friends don't work unless you open another window. Do you perhaps mean how to resize the modal itself? In which case, a modal is not a window and you'd be using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin

Here is what I tried

```
this.resizeBy(-1, -1);
this.resizeBy(+1, +1);

parene.resizeBy(-1, -1);
parent.resizeBy(+1, +1);
```

I added it at the bottom of a remote modal.

I have mapbox in the modal and it is not displaying correctly. I notice if you adjust the browser size, it fix itself. Wanted to try it and see if it worked...